# Azure B2C Custom Policy - Unable to set phone mfa for an existing user that has not logged in and can not log in until mfa is complete

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Our scenario: we create the user account in the portal but set the account to disabled. We then send an email invite to the user where it will take the user through a custom policy flow that will direct the user to set up phone mfa. If mfa is set, the user will become enabled and then will be able to sign in to the application.

However, I can not get PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify to execute in this scenario. However, during troubleshooting, if I enabled the account, sign in to the application and then sign out, and then run through the policy flow, it works as accepted. Can anyone provide any insight to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the account as enabled instead, and assign a random [password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#example-5).
2. Update the password after phone validation.